# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.' Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stream

hola amigos tengo este error `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'` cuando le doy scroll  a un listview que tengo, alguien sabe como puedo arreglar esto? o que me explique que esta pasando y como puedo preeverlo? 
este es mi codigo

```js
private async Task getWashers() {
  try {
    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) {
      var uri = "http://miapifelizuwu.com/washers/";
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
      request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
      var client = new HttpClient();



      try {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        switch (response.StatusCode) {
          case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 500");


            break;
          case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 200");

            try {
              HttpContent content = response.Content;
              string xjson = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


              var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < Washer >> (xjson);

              if (result.Count() > 0) {
                WasherList.ItemsSource = result;
                WasherList.ItemTapped += PickerWasher_ItemTapped;
              } else {

                wlbl.Text = "Lo sentimos no hay washers cerca de momento, intenta mas tarde";

                WasherList.IsVisible = false;
              }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
              await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
              var x = ex.ToString();

              return;
            }
            break;
          case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:

            await DisplayAlert("error 404", "servidor no encontrado ", "ok");
            break;
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {

        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Intente en otro momento _ error: " + ex.ToString() + " _ ", "ok");
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception exc) {

    await DisplayAlert("Error", "" + exc.ToString(), "ok");
  }

}
```

```html
<ListView x:Name="WasherList" ItemsSource="{Binding Washer}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="370" ItemTapped="PickerWasher_ItemTapped">
  <!--Built in Cells-->

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>


    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>

        <Frame x:Name="frame" CornerRadius="10" OutlineColor="#DCF8C6" BackgroundColor="white" Padding="0" HeightRequest="50" Margin="2,2,2,2">

          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,10,10">


            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="100">


              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="iko" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="50" />
                <Label Text="{Binding nombre}   " FontSize="Small" Margin="0,15,0,0" TextColor="#128C7E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />






                <lv:RatingConception ItemsNumber="5" DrawType="Star" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BlockVote="True" IsEnabled="False" ImageWidth="20" ImageHeight="20" DesignType="Standard" ColorUI="YellowLight" InitialValue="{Binding calificacion}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                  x:Name="ratingStar" />


              </Grid>
            </StackLayout>


          </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
      </ViewCell>

    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**getWashers** lo llamo cuando la se inizializa

```
 InitializeComponent();_=getWashers();
```

Comment: Probaria separar la llamada en otra clase diferente al viewmodel, y en el viewmodel le asignas la respuesta al Listview. Quizas el GC te esta limpiando los objetos. Luego deberia ver si CachingStrategy en el listview te ayuda, segun la necesidad

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo observar hay 2 soluciones alternativas que he usado, a continuacion le agrego ambas.

1. Usando su codigo:

   ```
   private async Task getWashers() {
     try {
       if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) {


     var uri = "http://miapifelizuwu.com/washers/";
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
     request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
     using (var client = new HttpClient())

           HttpResponseMessage response =  client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

           switch (response.StatusCode) {
             case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
               Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 500");


               break;
             case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
               Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 200");

               try {
                 HttpContent content = response.Content;
                 string xjson = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < Washer >> (xjson);

                 if (result.Count() > 0) {
                   WasherList.ItemsSource = result;
                   WasherList.ItemTapped += PickerWasher_ItemTapped;
                 } else {

                   wlbl.Text = "Lo sentimos no hay washers cerca de momento, intenta mas tarde";

                   WasherList.IsVisible = false;
                 }

               } catch (Exception ex) {
                 await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
                 var x = ex.ToString();

                 return;
               }
               break;
             case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:

               await DisplayAlert("error 404", "servidor no encontrado ", "ok");
               break;
           }    
       }
     } catch (Exception exc) {

       await DisplayAlert("Error", "" + exc.ToString(), "ok");
     }

   }
   ```

La segunda solucion es mas complicada pero puede resolver muchos mas problemas es implementar el accesso a la API con un HttpWebRequest. Esto aumenta el nivel de complejidad de la solucion pero te da mucho mas nivel de control.

```
...
var uri = "http://miapifelizuwu.com/washers/";    
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
{
   string contenido = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
 ....
}


....
```

Espero estas soluciones ayuden a resolver su problema.

Comment: pues me sigue dando el mismo erro System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

Comment: Usted intento las 2 soluciones? Si la respuesta es afirmativa, voy a necesitar mas detalles del error para poder brindarle ayuda.

Comment: para la solucion 2 debo hacer lo mismo y cuando quiera que mi hilo termine devolver esto?    string contenido = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
?

Comment: La solucion 2 solamente cambia la forma en que usted hace la solitud al API. 
Solucion orginal: string xjson = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Solucion 2: string contenido = streamReader.ReadToEnd();